# How to check if a sidereal time exists or belongs in sequence?

Tags: python

I want to check whether the sidereal time belongs in the sequence (`freq="2H"`) of 12 or not.

For example, if the sidereal time is `23:47:41.13`, then the return is `0`.

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

st = 23:47:41.13 #class 'ephem.Angle'
if st in pd.date_range("23:00:00", "1:00:00"):
    b = 0
elif st in pd.date_range("1:00:00", "3:00:00"):
    b = 1
elif st in pd.date_range("3:00:00", "5:00:00"):
    b = 2
elif st in pd.date_range("5:00:00", "7:00:00"):
    b = 3
elif st in pd.date_range("7:00:00", "9:00:00"):
    b = 4
elif st in pd.date_range("9:00:00", "11:00:00"):
    b = 5
elif st in pd.date_range("11:00:00", "13:00:00"):
    b = 6
elif st in pd.date_range("13:00:00", "15:00:00"):
    b = 7
elif st in pd.date_range("15:00:00", "17:00:00"):
    b = 8
elif st in pd.date_range("17:00:00", "19:00:00"):
    b = 9
elif st in pd.date_range("19:00:00", "21:00:00"):
    b = 10
else:
    b = 11
hour = b
print(b)
```

The above codes are not errors, but the return comes out  wrong. I don'k know how to do...
Please let me know that how to check whether a sidereal time exists in sequence?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to be sure... the time in the `date_ranges` is solar time, isn't it? So are you asking how to convert the sideral time to solar time before checking in which range it belongs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could get hour `23` from your time and calculate `divide by 2` (to get most of expected values), and result calculate `modulo 12` to get `0` instead of `12` for `23`

```
hour = 23    
print(hour, '->', ((hour+1)//2)%12)
```

Gives

```
23 -> 0
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
st = '23:47:41.13'
hour = int(str(st).split(':')[0])
print(st, '->', ((hour+1)//2)%12)
```

Gives expected `0`

```
23:47:41.13 -> 0
```

---

**EDIT:** This code shows that it gives correct results for other `hour` values - so it works correctly. And you need only `((hour+1)//2)%12` without all your `if/else` and `data_range()`

```
for hour in range(0, 24):
    print(hour, '->', ((hour+1)//2)%12)
```

Result

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
4 -> 2
5 -> 3
6 -> 3
7 -> 4
8 -> 4
9 -> 5
10 -> 5
11 -> 6
12 -> 6
13 -> 7
14 -> 7
15 -> 8
16 -> 8
17 -> 9
18 -> 9
19 -> 10
20 -> 10
21 -> 11
22 -> 11
23 -> 0
```

Comment: The above codes is different to the result I expected. I want to see the result of only one, not 12th. For example, the result of st = 23:47:41.13 #class 'ephem.Angle' should be to 0.

Comment: then use code from first example - `print(hour, '->', ((hour+1)//2)%12)` - without `for`-loop. Next example (with `for`-loop) is only to show that it gives correct results for other values too.